# Find $K=K(a,b)$ such that $\ln(x)<bx^a$ when $x>K$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a,b$ be two positive numbers. We know since polynomials grow faster than logarithms, $\ln(x)<bx^a$ will eventually hold as $x\to \infty$. However, is it possible to find one explicit $K$, depending on $a,b$, such that $\ln(x)<bx^a$ when $x>K$?

Ps: I am not asking for the smallest $K$ but I do need a verification of such $K$.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$e^t\ge1+t,$$ we have for $a\ge2$ and $x\ge\max\{1,\frac1b\}$,
$$ e^{bx^a}\ge1+bx^a\ge1+bx^2\ge 1+x>x$$
hence we can pick
$K=\max\{1,\tfrac1b\}$ if $a\ge2$.
If $a<2$, substitute $y=x^{a/2}$; then we want $by^2>\ln (y^{2/a})$, or $\frac{ab}2y^2>\ln(y)$. As just seen, it suffices to have $y\ge\max\{1,\frac2{ab}\}$, or $x\ge\max\{1,(\frac2{ab})^{2/a}\}$. Thus we can pick
$$ K=\max\left\{1,\frac 1b,\left(\frac2{ab}\right)^{\frac 2a}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $0 < ab \le 1/e$, the inequality is true for $$x > \left(\frac{-W_{-1}(-ab)}{ab}\right)^{1/a}$$ where $W_{-1}$ is the lower branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  If $ab > 1/e$, it is true for all $x > 0$.

Comment: well, this seems gives the smallest possible $K$ without a proof... Actually I am not asking for the smallest possible $K$ but I need a down-to-earth argument.